# data.table, filter >= median per group and keep two lowest

Tags: r, data.table

**Situation & Goal**

I'm having a large table that looks like (simplified):

```
|MainCat |SubCat | Value|
|:-------|:------|-----:|
|A       |Y      |    50|
|A       |Z      |    60|
|A       |ZZZZ   |    80|
|A       |XX     |    90|
|A       |X      |   100|
|B       |XYXY   |    15|
|B       |XXX    |    50|
|B       |YY     |    60|
|B       |ZZZ    |   150|
|B       |ZZ     |   400|
```

Now I want to filter each group (`MainCat`) and keep only the two lowest values (`Value`) that are equal/greater than median:

```
|MainCat |SubCat | Value|Comment               |
|:-------|:------|-----:|:---------------------|
|A       |Y      |    50|-                     |
|A       |Z      |    60|-                     |
|A       |ZZZZ   |    80|Median, First to keep |
|A       |XX     |    90|Second to keep        |
|A       |X      |   100|-                     |
|B       |XYXY   |    15|-                     |
|B       |XXX    |    50|-                     |
|B       |YY     |    60|Median, First to keep |
|B       |ZZZ    |   150|Second to keep        |
|B       |ZZ     |   400|-                     |
```

---

**Expected result:**

```
|MainCat |SubCat | Value|
|:-------|:------|-----:|
|A       |ZZZZ   |    80|
|A       |XX     |    90|
|B       |YY     |    60|
|B       |ZZZ    |   150|
```

---

**My (failed) attempt**

I tried `df2[Value >= df2[MainCat==MainCat, median(Value, na.rm=TRUE)]]` but this calculates a Median for all values, without grouping. Can somebody help? As performance is key, I prefer a `data.table` solution if possible. Thank you very much.

---

**MWE**

Base data:

```
df2 = structure(list(MainCat = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
                                 "B", "B", "B"), SubCat = c("Y", "Z", "ZZZZ", "XX", "X", "XYXY", 
                                                "XXX", "YY", "ZZZ", "ZZ"), Value = c(50, 60, 80, 90, 100, 15, 
                                                             50, 60, 150, 400)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                "data.frame"))
```

Result:

```
data.table(MainCat=c("A","A","B","B"),
                 SubCat=c("ZZZZ", "XX", "YY", "ZZZ"),
                 Value=c(80,90,60,150))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a group by 'MainCat', get the row index (`.I`) after creating the logical expression with the `median` 'Value', extract the index (`$V1`), subset the data, `order` by the 'MainCat', 'Value', get the first two rows with `head`, grouped by 'MainCat'

```
library(data.table)
df2[df2[, .I[Value >= median(Value, na.rm = TRUE)],.(MainCat)]$V1
    ][order(MainCat, Value), head(.SD, 2), MainCat]
```

-output

```
   MainCat SubCat Value
    <char> <char> <num>
1:       A   ZZZZ    80
2:       A     XX    90
3:       B     YY    60
4:       B    ZZZ   150
```

Comment: I can just repeat like always: thank you akrun! Upvote and accepted (as soon as it is possible)!